# Laplace transforms to solve heat equation

Tags: laplace-transform

I have the heat equation $$\frac{\partial u}{\partial t}=\frac{\partial^2 u}{\partial x^2}$$
Boundary conditions are $u=0$ at $x=0$ and $x=1$

The initial condition is $u=\sin(\pi x)$

I know that $$L \left(\frac{\partial u}{\partial t}\right)=sL(u)-\sin(\pi x)$$

Then the next step in my notes is $$L\left( \frac{\partial^2 u}{\partial x^2}\right)=\frac{\partial^2}{\partial x^2}(L(u))$$

Where does this step come from and what does it mean?

Comment: Presumably it is a typo and should read $(L(u))_{xx}$

Comment: What is your definition of the Laplace transform?

Comment: @AntonioVargas: Did you mean $L((u)_{xx})$?

Comment: @copper.hat : The Laplace transform would be in the t variable, not in x.

Comment: @T.A.E.: Thanks. I realise that for nice $u$ that $L(u_{xx}) = (L(u))_{xx}$, but perhaps this is where the OP was stumbling?

Comment: @copper.hat : Could be. I see how you're thinking now.

Comment: @T.A.E.: It is also entirely feasible, as is often the case, that I missed a point :-).

Comment: @ antoniovagas  Sorry I missed a little detail in my post.

Comment: @ copper.hat sorry I missed a little detail in my OP which I have added in now

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To see what the step
$$L\left(\frac{\partial^2 u}{\partial x^2}\right) = \frac{\partial^2}{\partial x^2}(L(u))$$
means, write both sides out using the definition of the (one-sided) Laplace transform:
$$
\underbrace{\int_0^\infty e^{-st}\left(\frac{\partial^2}{\partial x^2}u(x,t)\right)\,dt}_{L\left(\frac{\partial^2 u}{\partial x^2}\right)} =
\underbrace{\frac{\partial^2}{\partial x^2}\int_0^\infty e^{-st}u(x,t)\,dt}_{\frac{\partial^2}{\partial x^2}(L(u))}.
$$
Essentially, it says we're assuming $u(x,t)$ is regular enough in $x$ and $t$ to allow [differentiation under the integral sign](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Differentiation_under_the_integral_sign).